# iOS Swift project, have Objective-C file and I want to import a swift class to the Objective-C file

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bridging-header, objc-bridging-header

I have a Swift project, and I successfully added some Objective C class files into this Swift project and able to use it in the project, using bridging header.

Now in these Objective C classes, I want to import a Swift class. How can I do this?

I've searched a lot but not found any answers for this yet. Most answered questions are about how to import Objective-C class into Swift project, or import Swift class into Objective-C project. But my case is different

Comment: I've searched a lot but not found any answers for this yet. Most answered questions are about how to import Objective-C class into Swift project, or import Swift class into Objective-C project. But my case is different

Comment: If importing a swift class into an Objective-C *file* is somehow different to importing it into an Objective-C *project*, you need to explain how it's different and not answered by the marked duplicate.

Comment: I have a swift project and I already imported obj-c classes, let say testClass.h & testClass.m, to use in the project. Now in testClass.m, I want to import a swift class, let say mySwiftClass.swift into .m file to use. How can I do that?